# Необходимо ли трогать авторскую пунктуацию?

Tags: авторская-пунктуация

> Каждый вечер мой путь лежал на набережную – **там, несколько лет назад,
>   в старых доках,** устроили с десяток приятных ресторанов, превратив
>   пустующую промышленную зону в подобие очага столичной жизни.

Comment: Как вариант: _Каждый вечер мой путь лежал на набережную – там, несколько лет назад, в старых доках устроили..._ (без запятой после "доках").

Comment: Слава, спасибо! Главное, автор всё увидит: выберет милый сердцу варьянт правки. А что не править нельзя, вычислит по нашим переговорам. )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне всё нравится.

Каждый вечер мой путь лежал на набережную – там, *несколько лет назад, в старых доках*, устроили с десяток приятных ресторанов, превратив пустующую промышленную зону в подобие очага столичной жизни.

О правилах

С одной стороны, местоименное наречие *там*  является обстоятельством места, его содержание раскрывает обстоятельство *в старых доках*. Но в расширенном понимании мы можем отнести к *там* и обстоятельство времени: там – когда, где. Всё это можно обособить и прочитать с перечислением.

Comment: Мау, спасибо. Я уже вышла из положения наипростецким образом: перетащила место к месту, высвободив из их плена время: ***там, в старых доках, несколько лет назад  устроили с десяток приятных ресторанов...***

Comment: Да, хорошо. Читается нормально, и пунктуация уже не авторская, а по правилам.

Comment: Пунктуацию автор - а я с ним тут не раз ещё возникну - отдаёт в полное наше распоряжение, а вот лексика - это такое личное-преличное! Со знаками как раз нужно тексту отчаянно помогать, потому что автор - великолепный рассказчик, можно разные интервью на Ютубе посмотреть: Инга Ильм.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, а великолепный рассказчик чувствуется.

Comment: Галина, ваш вариант исправления буквально напрашивается: "там" должно соседствовать с местом, а не временем!

Comment: А ммне кажется, что должно, но не обязано. Это же не школьный текст, где всё строго соответствует правилам, а учитель проверяет.  У автора вся информация была обособлена, выделена, а в исправленном виде выделено только обстоятельство места, а это уже небольшое отступление от авторского варианта.  На одной стороне - формальные правила, а на другой стороне - автоский строй предложения. Есть из чего выбирать.

Comment: Хоть один интересный пример! Первый случай также имеет право на жизнь на основании "разрыва" главного слова и уточнения другими конструкциями. Так что оба случая верны.

Answer (score 0):

Авторская пунктуация потому и "авторская", что игнорирует правила. А *по закону* запятых вообще не должно быть в выделенном фрагменте. Чисто по ощущениям - меня эта несколько натужная попытка показать паузы *живой речи* в *письменном тексте* коробит именно натужностью, не вызванной никакой реальной необходимостью. Но выбор - за автором и корректором